# using grunt-rev and usemin inside the css file

Tags: grunt-usemin

I'm looking for a way to make grunt usemin fix the generated css fill to reference the new`rev` generated img name in  in some  url using css proprties (background-image etc). usemin handles the change in all of my html files, but not in the css. 
similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705899/usemin-and-rewriting-urls-of-images-in-vendor-css-files-using-grunt) except it's not a vendor issue, so I have (some) control over the css (`less` generated) and I hoped this problem is already solved.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [usemin and rewriting urls of images in vendor CSS files using Grunt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705899/usemin-and-rewriting-urls-of-images-in-vendor-css-files-using-grunt)