# Managing images in bower packages using grunt

Tags: express, gruntjs, bower

I have an express app in which I'm using bower to manage the front-end dependencies. I'm also using grunt to build the front end by concatenating, uglifying, minifying, and rev'ing all the assets, including the scripts/styles that ship with each bower component using [`grunt-usemin`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin).

To accomplish this I'm moving all of the compiled assets (including bower scripts/styles) to a `dist/public` directory. I end up with a `<cache-buster>.vendor.js` and a `<cache-buster>.vendor.css` file, which contain all of the *optimized* bower components.

The question is, how should I manage images that ship with various bower packages? I could manually move them into my `images` folder, but I would prefer to leave them packaged in `bower_components` (where they belong, in my opinion) and leave it up to grunt during the build process.

Any input would be appreciated.

---

**Gruntfile.js (extract)**

```
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          src: [
            'dist/public/css/{,*/}*.css',
            'dist/public/js/{,*/}*.js',
            'dist/public/img/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },

    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: 'dist/public'
      },
      jade: ['dist/views/{,*/}*.jade']
    },

    usemin: {
      jade: ['dist/views/{,*/}*.jade'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['dist/public'],
        patterns: {
          jade: require('usemin-patterns').jade
        }
      }
    },

    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'stylus', 'coffee'
      ],
      dist: [
        'stylus', 'coffee'
      ]
    },

    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'views',
          dest: 'dist/views',
          src: '{,*/}*.jade'
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:server',
    'express:server',
    'watch'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'copy:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);
```

---

**layout.jade (extract)**

```
//-<!-- build:css(assets) css/vendor.css -->
link(href='/bower_components/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css')
//-<!-- endbuild -->

//-<!-- build:css(.tmp) css/application.css -->
link(href='/css/one.css')
link(href='/css/two.css')
//-<!-- endbuild -->

//-<!-- build:js(assets) js/vendor.js -->
script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/bower_components/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js')
//-<!-- endbuild -->

//-<!-- build:js(.tmp) js/application.js -->
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/one.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/two.js')
//-<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Why not simply add a `copy:images` target?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254068/how-to-rewrite-urls-of-images-in-vendor-css-files-using-grunt

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how a `copy:images` target would work. Thanks for the link Anzeo.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution adapted to your Gruntfile:

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      src: [
        'dist/public/css/{,*/}*.css',
        'dist/public/js/{,*/}*.js',
        'dist/public/img/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
        'dist/bower_components/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg,eot,ttf,woff}'
      ]
    }]
  }
},
useminPrepare: {
  options: {
    dest: 'dist/public',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  },
  jade: ['dist/views/{,*/}*.jade']
},

cssmin: {
  options: {
    root: 'src'
  }
},
```

This assumes your bower_compontents directory is located in a source directory called 'src'.  In my environment (bootstrapped with Yeoman) it was in 'app', so you may need to tweak cssmin.

Here is what is happening:

First, we add rev checksums to a bunch of possible resource files in the bower_components directory.

Next, the `flow` configuration tells usemin to skip the `concat` step for css files. This is because `cssmin` does a concatenation itself, and `cssmin` needs to know the origin of the css files in order to do the relative-path correction for referenced resources.

Lastly, the `root` config tells cssmin which path to start searching from to find the resources.

You can check to verify the results are correct by going to `dist/styles/<cache-buster>.vendor.css` and verifying the images have relative URLs, starting with /bower-components/

For example, in my build, I have bootstrap.css embedded in my vendor.css, and it has been rewritten like this:

```
@font-face{
   font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
   src:url(/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/2ad0632b.glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
```

(line wrapping added for legibility, its all cssminified in reality).

I hope this helps.

Giving credit where it is due, I found this originally here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415649/1017787 I've adjusted it to your configuration and added the revision config.